# How to use variable named scopes with attributes of associated models OTHER than id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, named-scope

I'm having trouble with getting a named scope working using using an attribute of the associated model other than the id column.

I have a Firm model which has a city_id column.
I also have a City model with a name column.

I want to get restful urls like this so as to make use of the has_scope gem and have skinny controllers

```
http://localhost:3000/firms?by_city=Dublin
```

However using the present code I can only insert the city Id

```
http://localhost:3000/firms?by_city=546
```

Here is my named_route

```
class Firm < ActiveRecord::Base       
named_scope :by_city, proc {|city| { :conditions => { :city => city } } }
end
```

Any ideas about how to modify the named scope so as to generate urls using the name would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add `belongs_to` to the Firm class and then for the named scope add a join on city so you can get to the city's name in the query.  Something like this

```
class Firm < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  named_scope :by_city, lambda {|city_name| {:joins => :city, :conditions => {:city => {:name => city_name}}}}
end
```

Comment: Thanks - this works but requires a slight modification
 

  named_scope :by_city, lambda {|city_name| {:joins => :city, :conditions => {:cities => {:name => city_name}}}}